# resample duplicate time series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following time series

```
time             sensor  status
2017-11-20 12:28:16 SM4 Movement
2017-11-20 12:28:18 SM4 No movement
2017-11-20 12:28:20 SM4 Movement
2017-11-20 12:28:20 SM3 Movement
2017-11-20 12:28:20 SM3 No movement
2017-11-20 12:28:23 D03 Open
2017-11-20 12:28:25 C13 Open
```

I want to resample the duplicate datetimeindex and get this index as duplicated in final resampled dataframe as will

```
df= pd.read_csv(r'.........p\gg.csv', parse_dates=['time'], index_col= 'time')

df=df.resample('s').first().ffill()
```

I get

```
time            sensor  status      
2017-11-20 12:28:16 SM4 Movement
2017-11-20 12:28:17 SM4 Movement
2017-11-20 12:28:18 SM4 No movement
2017-11-20 12:28:19 SM4 No movement
2017-11-20 12:28:20 SM4 Movement
2017-11-20 12:28:21 SM4 Movement
2017-11-20 12:28:22 SM4 Movement
2017-11-20 12:28:23 D03 Open
2017-11-20 12:28:24 D03 Open
2017-11-20 12:28:25 C13 Open
```

I have tried

```
df.set_index('time', inplace=True)
```

I would expect

```
time             sensor status          
2017-11-20 12:28:16 SM4 Movement
2017-11-20 12:28:17 SM4 Movement
2017-11-20 12:28:18 SM4 No movement
2017-11-20 12:28:19 SM4 No movement
2017-11-20 12:28:20 SM4 Movement
2017-11-20 12:28:21 SM4 Movement
2017-11-20 12:28:22 SM4 Movement
2017-11-20 12:28:20 SM3 Movement
2017-11-20 12:28:21 SM3 Movement
2017-11-20 12:28:22 SM3 Movement
2017-11-20 12:28:20 SM3 No movement
2017-11-20 12:28:21 SM3 No movement
2017-11-20 12:28:22 SM3 No movement
```

Comment: what you expect looks weird... time should only go in one direction. Unless you're Marty McFly. Anyway, maybe you could clarify what you mean by resampling?

Comment: as you can see resampling works perfectly, it segements my data into bins of seconds but the only problem is when two or three sensors fires at the same time resample will segment the first of duplicated second and ignore others... yes you are right it is not according to the basic concept of resample but i can not loose my senor that fired at the same time.. i need to take that in to consideration for analysis

Comment: alright, if memory is not an issue, I'd just use one column for each sensor. That would make a lot of missing values, but who cares... it would make the `df` easier to read/interpret and process further imho. And the space-time continuum would not be in danger ;-)